# possible to use #ifndef on a function name?

Tags: c++, c, ifndef

I'm working with [MicroPython](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/blob/master/py/mphal.h) and their header files use a ton of

```
#ifndef function_name
void function_name(const char *str, size_t len);
#endif
```

Using both an online C and C++ compiler, I tried the following code to test this in both C++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func();    

#ifndef func
int a = 5;
#else
int a = 3;
#endif    

int main()
{
  cout << "a = " << a << endl;
}
```

And in C

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func();


#ifndef func
int a = 5;
#else
int a = 3;
#endif


int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    printf("a = %d\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

and both times, I got `5` which means using `#ifndef` on function names doesn't work.

**QUESTION**

Is there some special compiler flag that enables this feature or do they have a bug?

Comment: " both times, I got 5 which means using #ifndef on function names doesn't work." - that's because it doesn't work.

Comment: `#if(n)def` only works with things declared with `#define`. So, I'm guessing that MicroPython allows `function_name` to be defined as a preprocessor macro, eg `#define function_name(str, len) ...`, and if it is not defined as a macro then `#ifndef function_name` is used to declare `function_name` as a real C/C++ function instead

Comment: *"Is there some special compiler flag that enables this feature or do they have a bug?"* That's quite a wrong dichotomy. You just completely misunderstood what `#ifndef` does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#ifndef X` checks if a *macro* with the name `X` has been defined. Function names and macro names belong to different name spaces. Presence or absence of function `X` would not affect `#ifndef X`.